# python3: Can I get cartesian product of 'one' 3d list?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have a list looks like below

`[['a'], ['b'], [[1], [2], [3]], ['d']]`

and I need to get

`[['a'], ['b'], [1], ['d']]`, `[['a'], ['b'], [2], ['d']]`, `[['a'], ['b'], [3], ['d']]`

I saw few posts and found itertools.product, but I think this needs multiple lists in same dimension as argument.

Is there any way to get the result?

Comment: `itertools.product(*your_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` with the star operator (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean)).

That would look like

```
from itertools import product
A = [['a'], ['b'], [[1], [2], [3]], ['d']]

for a in product(*A):
   print(a)

# yields
# ('a', 'b', [1], 'd')
# ('a', 'b', [2], 'd')
# ('a', 'b', [3], 'd')
```